# How is javascript able to retain variable from a Promise?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript/Typescript code that looks like this:

```
for (let item of itemList) {
  this.myService.myMethodReturningPromise(item.id).then(success => {
    item.value = success;
  });
}
```

By the time my Promise resolves, I have already exited the loop and I no longer have reference to `item`.

Why is it able to correctly set the value of each item in `itemList`?

Comment: Ordinary scoping rules. Even if the main thread has ended, the function is still a *closure* and can see the `item`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right, in other words, you can get access to `item` only inside this `for` loop (if you will not additionally store the value outside the loop).

Comment: @CertainPerformance  `main thread has ended,`   you didn't really mean to say that did you?.  :)

Comment: Thanks. Closures are really confusing but at least now I know what that happens.

Comment: @Keith I *think* that's the proper way to say it - the main thread runs, finishes, then asynchronous Promises and setTimeouts and such have a chance to resolve. Might it be phrased differently?

Comment: @CertainPerformance  There is only ever 1 thread in JS, the main thread.  I think you could just say the loop has finished.  It's not a big deal :),  with all the new Async stuff with JS, it's easy to forget it's not threaded.  And at its core works similar to a cooperative multi-tasking OS.